# Is the product $(p^2+1)/(p^2-1)$ for all $p$ rational? For all $n$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, infinite-product

Is this product: 
\begin{align*}
\prod_{\text{$p$ prime}}\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}
\end{align*}
rational? What is the value of it? What about for the natural numbers $p>1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\frac{p^2 + 1}{p^2 - 1}$, rather than $p^2 + p^{-2} - 1$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, your right

Comment: What's $n$ in the title of the question?